# File uploader interceptor deletes files before action completes its execution

Tags: java, struts2, tomcat7, apache-commons-fileupload

Server: Tomcat 7x

Struts2 File upload interceptor

Note: File successfully uploaded to default server location: ../work/catalina/localhost/projectWebAppName/

Issue: Uploaded file deleted before completing action

Question: Is tomcat deleting the uploaded file or File upload interceptor deleting before completing action

Comment: Define "before completing action". The `FileUploadInterceptor` deletes the file when the request flow back through. In order to keep the file, copy it elsewhere.

Comment: The FileUploadInterceptor will delete the file only after executing the action class. If this is the correct statement then uploaded file should available untill the action class is executed. Note:This is an intermittent problem. Temporary solution that we are using it by deleting files from work/Catalina/localhost/projWebAppFolder..

Comment: My action class (say FileUploadAction) making use of file upload interceptor to upload file. This action class will validate and process the uploaded file. But the uploaded file is available for validation and unavailable to process.